# list of javascript objects/features unique to a given browser?

Tags: javascript

Has anyone seen a list of features unique to a given browser? For example, if you want to target just IE 8 acting like itself, you could do:

```
if (typeof document.documentMode != undefined) {
if (document.documentMode == 8) {
    ...stuff
}
```

}

Likewise, for all versions of IE you could check for window.clipboardData . But what about Firefox and webkit? I'm specifically trying to detect webkit at the moment, but I've been looking for a list like this for ages without luck.

Answer (score 2):

jQuery has/had pretty [robust browser checking](http://docs.jquery.com/Utilities/jQuery.browser), but has migrated towards [specific feature checking](http://docs.jquery.com/Utilities/jQuery.support). Check them out for some hints.

Answer (score 2):

[Quirksmode](http://www.quirksmode.org/) has always been great for this type of info.

Answer (score 2):

Your way of targeting browsers is flawed.

You check for the existence of a global variable to determine what browser you are in, but if any script which is included in your web page sets a *documentMode* global variable, your code will break. There are other ways to do browser detection (*navigator.appName*  and *navigator.appVersion* for example), do a google search on the subject and you will find more detail.